# Microservice, bounded context and shared data

Tags: microservices, bounded-contexts

I'm researching about Microservices Architecture and I concern about shared data between services as master data of the system. Example, in my system I have 2 
business contexts "Import Booking" and "Import Invoice".

- Import Booking uses Company information to validate and create new Company if not exists.
- Import Invoice uses Company information to validate.

So, the system will have 3 services "Import Booking", "Import Invoice", "Company Service" and "Company Service" will expose an API for another services to CRUD or the system only have 2 services "Import Booking" and "Import Service" and CRUD Company will implement in each service.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your bounded context and service boundaries a bit off, look at this talk: https://vimeo.com/284707733 "Finding your service boundaries - a practical guide - Adam Ralph".

I'd recommend learning more about distributed systems also, you can't really lift a monolith into a Microservice architecture without doing a big paradigm shift...